# How to acquire a dead Twitter account that uses your domain name?

Tags: twitter

I just obtained a domain for a new website, let's call it `xyz.com`.

I'm quite annoyed at the fact there is a Twitter user with the handle `@xyz`

For a professional appearance I would like to acquire this Twitter account to use in my marketing and not have to settle for something like `@xyzapp`

The word squatter is inappropriate because that implies a certain intent, this user may have just signed up and never used their account. But regardless...

1. They signed up in 2009
2. They have never posted once and follow zero people

I would like to get in touch with this user, but for privacy reasons I doubt Twitter would provide me with their contact information. Since they have been inactive on Twitter for over a decade I don't expect them to respond to my messages.

What is the best way to go about this situation? I would be willing to pay a reasonable fee for the user to surrender the account to me, but this is also against Twitter rules. So I'm not even sure how to proceed.

Comment: This account may still be in use by someone who just reads or follows people with a private account.

Comment: in the rare circumstance that the Twitter account was tied to the domain, configure a catchall email address and wait and see if Twitter is sending emails to an address on the domain.

Answer (score 7):

The key to claim and obtain a Twitter handle is to submit documentation that proves the desired handle is **a registered trademark, or a legitimate established brand**. Years ago I successfully obtained an inactive Twitter handle whose name was also the name of a theatre company by submitting a company dossier and links to the website. You have to be as thorough as possible and **use a corporate e-mail from the referenced brand** when using the Twitter form.

Check the Twitter policy here:

https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/inactive-twitter-accounts